# How can you negate the effects of CSS translate on the overflow of the parent

Tags: html, css

When you apply something like `transform: translateX(100%)` on an element, it will be moved 100% of its size to the right. This will also extend the scroll container in that direction, thus creating a vertical scrollbar.

I have created a small snippet to demonstrate this:

```js
isTrans = false;

function sw() {
  document.querySelector('#trans-element').style.transform = isTrans ? '' : 'translateX(100%)';
  isTrans = !isTrans;
}
```

```css
#scroll-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#trans-element {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sw()">Switch Translate</button>

<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="trans-element"></div>
</div>
```

Could this somehow be negated? I have thought about wrapping the translated object into another div with `overflow: hidden`, but would like to avoid this method, as it seems really intrusive to the CSS flow.

For completeness’s sake I have added a snippet for that as well:

```js
isTrans = false;

function sw() {
  document.querySelector('#trans-element').style.transform = isTrans ? '' : 'translateX(100%)';
  isTrans = !isTrans;
}
```

```css
#scroll-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

#trans-element {
  width: 100%; /* Now has to be 100% width/height and no margin */
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

#hide-overflow {
  width: 500px;  /* Needs to have width/height of what the element should have */
  height: 50px; /* and also needs to hold the margin information */
  margin-top: 20px;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sw()">Switch Translate</button>

<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="hide-overflow">
    <div id="trans-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think some parent somewhere will need `overflow: hidden`, if not immediate parent then something like `body`.

Comment: Unless you can use `position: fixed;` on it

Comment: @TJ Yeah was my thought too, but I was optimistic that there might be some way to avoid this mess. Maybe even another property to archive the same effect (moving an element out of screen and moving it in when it is in viewport)

Comment: If this child doesnt contain  content you can use `scaleX` to shrink it on the X axis

Comment: @CharlesLavalard thanks for the input - there is content unfortunately

Comment: Yeah so if you want movement you will have to use `overflow: hidden` to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of way to achieve this but your example is too minimalistic to know which on is suitable for your real use case.

One example is to change the direction of the container:

```js
isTrans = false;

function sw() {
  document.querySelector('#trans-element').style.transform = isTrans ? '' : 'translateX(100%)';
  isTrans = !isTrans;
}
```

```css
#scroll-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  
  direction:rtl;
}

#trans-element {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sw()">Switch Translate</button>

<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="trans-element"></div>
</div>
```

Or simulate the translation using clip-path

```js
isTrans = false;

function sw() {
  document.querySelector('#trans-element').style.clipPath = isTrans ? '' : 'inset(0 0 0 100%)';
  isTrans = !isTrans;
}
```

```css
#scroll-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  
}

#trans-element {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  
  background-color: red;
  clip-path:inset(0);
  transition: clip-path .5s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sw()">Switch Translate</button>

<div id="scroll-container">
  <div id="trans-element"></div>
</div>
```